# How do I return 0 using bitwise operations?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have the following function

```
int sign(int x) {

  int sign = (x >> 31);
  sign = sign | 1;
  return sign;

}
```

I wish for the following:

- return -1 for a negative number (first line)
- return 1 for a positive number (second line)
- return 0 for zero

I'm stuck on this last item.  How can I use the bitwise operators only to return zero if x is zero?

Comment: Why are you using bitwise operations for this?  One answer is `if (x == 0) return 0;` but doesn't that count?

Comment: Also, consider using `sizeof` instead of hard-coding the sizes

Comment: Does `sign = sign | !!x;` count?

Comment: If this is not a pure intellectual exercise: don't. `if`/`else` may not look exotic, but it works *and it's trivial to see that it works*.

Comment: ^^ Agree. write code for humans to read than just compiler. "Always think that your code reviewer is a maniac serial killer, who knows where you live :D" - A saying.

Comment: Many good solutions here: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CopyIntegerSign

Comment: `return (x) ? ((x>>31) ? -1 : 1) : 0;`

Comment: This does not appear to be a practical problem. Just write the code in a straightforward manner.

Comment: @DanielFischer !! is Boolean, not bitwise.

Comment: @Medinoc Yes, the question is how serious the OP is with "only bitwise".

Comment: This is not practical. All processors support arithmetic comparison operations. There is no practical reason to limit yourself to bitwise operations. If your goal is to make the code as efficient as possible, then use `(x > 0) - (x < 0)`, which compiles to 7 jump-free instructions on x86. (Other processors will probably perform similarly.) It's also portable to any integer size, and any integer representation (1s complement, sign-magnitude, padding bits, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice little puzzle. Assume you have 32 bit ints:

```
int sign( int x )
{
   // if any bit is on, all bits are on. else zero.
   int lowBit = x;
   lowBit |= lowBit >> 16;
   lowBit |= lowBit >> 8;
   lowBit |= lowBit >> 4;
   lowBit |= lowBit >> 2;
   lowBit |= lowBit >> 1;
   lowBit &= 1;

   int signBit = x & 0x80000000;
   signBit |= signBit >> 16;
   signBit |= signBit >> 8;
   signBit |= signBit >> 4;
   signBit |= signBit >> 2;
   signBit |= signBit >> 1;
   signBit &= 0xFFFFFFFE;

   return signBit | lowBit;
}
```

Here is how it works. I'll explain with 4 bit numbers, but the explanation generalizes. You have to make a mapping from three categories of bit patterns:

```
0000    -> 0000
0xxx    -> 0001
1yyy    -> 1111
```

where x can be anything except 000, and yyy can be anything.

So first you want a bit that is 1 if any bit in the register is 1, and 0 otherwise. So we 'smear' the register, such that if any bit is high all bits are high, and we keep that bit for the value of the low bit in our result.

Then we 'smear' the sign bit. Finally we 'or' them together.

Exercise for the reader: If you have 32 bit ints, but 64 bit registers, you can cut the number of operations in half.

update: It can always be done better (untested):

```
int sign( int x )
{
   int lowBit = !!x;  // double ! operator, wtf? yes...

   int signBit = x & 0x80000000;
   signBit |= signBit >> 16;
   signBit |= signBit >> 8;
   signBit |= signBit >> 4;
   signBit |= signBit >> 2;
   signBit |= signBit >> 1;
   signBit &= 0xFFFFFFFE;

   return signBit | lowBit;
}
```

Comment: The above code relies on implementation-defined behavior (right-shifting a negative number).

Comment: Thinking about it - it works either way. Sane platforms will pad all right shifted numbers with zero. Dumb platforms will pad negative numbers with 1 and positives with 0. Either way the code works. It would only fail on insane platforms that would pad positive numbers with 1.

Comment: Or platforms where the top bit is not the sign bit. For example, it might be a parity bit or used to indicate a trap value. This is permitted by 6.2.6.2(2). Also, your code treats negative zero as less than zero rather than equal to zero.

Comment: I dare you to find a computer which is not in a museum that uses any of those.

Comment: I dare you to find a computer which is not in a museum which is incapable of comparing two integers with the `<` operator. (By the way, the answer to your question is the [Unisys ClearPath Dorado](http://www.unisys.com/unisys/theme/index.jsp?id=1120000970018010225&pid=16000034), which is still in active support.)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
int sign(int x) {

  int sign = (x >> 31);
  sign = sign | (~(1<<((x|(x>>5)|(x>>10)|(x>>15)|(x>>20)|(x>>25)|(x>>30))&0x1F))&0x1);
  return sign;

}
```

The idea is to left shift `1` with `x` count.

So if `x==0` then the first bit will be kept `1`

and if `x!=0` then the first bit will be changed to `0`

and then the `sign = sign | (~(First bit))`

it's equivalent to

```
sign = sign | (~(1<<x) & 0x1);
```

but we have to be careful when we left shift `1` with `x`, because `x` could be >= to the size of the type format (32) and the `x` could be negatif and for both cases it is undefined behavior.

so to avoid the above problem I split our 32 bits (the `x`) to 7 blocs each bloc contains 5 bits except the last one it contains 2 bits and then I made a `|` for all the blok

```
y=(bloc1|bloc2|bloc3|bloc4|bloc5|bloc6|bloc7)
```

so if `x!= 0` then `y!=0`

and if `x==0` then `y==0`

and we have to take only the first 5 bits of `y` (`&0x1F`). here I m sure that `y` is not negatif and `y<32`

and then instead of shifting with `x` I can shift with `y` to avoid the undefined behavior

Answer (score 0):

you can use also this. it has the same logic with my previous answer

```
int sign(int x) {
  int y = x;
  y |= y >> 16;
  y |= y >> 8;
  y |= y >> 4;
  y &= 0xF;

  int sign = (x >> 31);
  sign = sign | (~(1<<y) & 0x1);
  return sign;
}
```